# Crystal XI - How to find difference between 2 customer prices for same item

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a table that lists customer number, item number and item price (based on customer number).  What I'd like to do in Crystal is show the difference in item price for each customer/item number as compared against the item price for a specific customer ('Jeremy').  For example:

```
Customer name = Jeremy
price for item 1 = $20
price for item 2 = $30
price for item 3 = $40

Customer name = Mike
price for item 1 = $10
price for item 2 = $25
price for item 3 = $30
```

For all customers and  all items show:
Current Customer's name, Current item name, and Difference between Jeremy's item price and Current Customer's item price.
i.e.
    Mike, item 1, $10 (difference)
    Mike, item 2, $5  (difference)
    Mike, item 3, $10 (difference)

I'm getting hung up on how to show the price difference between the current customer's item price compared against Jeremy's item price for every item (and then repeat the same step for every customer as compared against Jeremy).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest before read further comment. Try to get this value from stored procedure or say when you get the data , add one column of compare value. Which is faster solution and nothing to be worry in crystal report side.

**I had done this type of issue in db side, not crystal report side.**

Still you want to in crystal report, then you can achieve by formula in variable.

You have to store the value in each variable in detail section and at the time of result , just compare.

or

You can do by the cross-tab report and at last you just give add formulated variable which gives the result, but this is tedious job.

Comment: The database idea sounds good, but I don't have the access needed to insert a table/stored procedure at the database level.  I like the idea of a sub-report and have been messing around with creating one with shared variables, however in the actual database there's close to 1,000 items so I don't want to have to create variables for each item.  Ideally i'd like to get the item number passed to two formulas, one that calculates the jeremy price and one that creates the Mike price.  Then I could create a third formula that returns the difference between the two prices.

Comment: Yes dear, You are in right direction. But one thing to be noted with shared variable that you must know how to shared variable used. It is static in whole report. so change the value when item change in item group. Right the formula in item group Header- section. It is tedious job. But I think you go with this. All the best

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this... but the best way I suggest is to use sub reports.

My Approach:

1. Take 2 sub reports in main report and create 2 detail sections and place each in one detail section.
2. In first sub report write below formulas and pass to the main report using sub report links.

@Item1

```
Shared numbervar item1;
if(Customer name = "Jeremy")
then item1:=Item1 database value
```

@Item2

```
Shared numbervar item2;
if(Customer name = "Jeremy")
then item2:=Item2 database value
```

@Item3

```
Shared numbervar item3;
if(Customer name = "Jeremy")
then item3:=Item3 database value
```

now pass the value to main report and store in varaibles.

@Main_Item1

```
Shared numbervar item1;
Shared numbervar item4;
item4:=item1;
```

@Main_Item2

```
Shared numbervar item5;
Shared numbervar item2;
item5:=item5;
```

@Main_Item3

```
Shared numbervar item6;
Shared numbervar item3;
item6:=item3;
```

now create second sub report and pass the values of `item4`, `item5` and `item6` to sub report 2 using sub report links.

Group by customer in sub report 2:

@display_item1

```
Shared numbervar item4;

if (customer name <> "jeremy")
then
item4-item1
```

@display_item2

```
Shared numbervar item5;

if (customer name <> "jeremy")
then
item5-item5
```

@display_item3

```
Shared numbervar item6;

if (customer name <> "jeremy")
then
item6-item3
```

now supress sub report 1 and don't supress sub report 2.

Now in your display sub report 2 has all values that are the difference of customer `Jeremy`.. if you want jeremy values to be displayed then change the above condition to `=Jeremy` in another formula.

Let me know if you face any issue.